# Different meaning of slapping the left or right cheek

Tags: history

I had this conversation with a colleague today and can't verify or falsify his words.
In Christianity Jesus' quote

> But if anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to him the other also

is usually seen as an act of non-resistance, but according to my colleague in ancient Judaism there had been a difference on which cheek you slap people.

Relatives or close people would be slapped on the right cheek while plebs and strangers you'd strike on the left cheek.
Is there any source at all for that?

Comment: Kohelet see in kohelet there is a verse saying this but the meaning is not the same.

Comment: @kouty - would you mind giving me the verse you're referring to?

Comment: Eicha sorry....

Comment: To close voters: The OP is specifically asking for a concept in Judaism. How is this off-topic? (Before anyone gets any ideas, it’s not comparative religion, either, since it presents all necessary outside information in the post itself.)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Qohelet and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I think @kouty was referring to https://www.sefaria.org/Lamentations.3.30?lang=bi.  But this advice is not for general usage.  It's specifically for when times are really really bad and there's nothing you can do to improve them, you accept it and wait for God to make things better.

Comment: Yes but I cancelled my answer

Comment: If the question is about Judaisim, there is no reason to quote the texts of other religions. If it's not about Judaisim, it's not on-topic.

Comment: @JoshK He quotes the texts of other religions as motivation for his question. No different than any number of other such questions on this site.

Comment: @Heshy - I wasn't aware of this reference. It has a different background, but I'd like to learn more about it. Can you recommend any further explanation for this verse?

Comment: @JoshK - it's for context only. Asking this kind of question out of context seemed to be weird as it would be just one sentence out of the blue. It's not my intention to discuss the quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jewish sources have an extremely negative view of slapping a person in the face; regardless if it's the right cheek, or the left one.

The Talmud ([Sanhedrin 58b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.58b.18?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)) teaches:

> And Rabbi Ḥanina says: One who slaps the cheek of a Jew is considered
>   as though he slapped the cheek of the Divine Presence; as it is
>   stated: “It is a snare [mokesh] for a man to rashly say [yala]:
>   Holy” (Proverbs 20:25).

The verse is interpreted homiletically to mean: One who strikes [nokesh] a Jew is considered as though he hurt the cheek [lo’a] of the Holy One.

[Rabbi Eliezer Papo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Papo), in his ethical work "[Pele Yoetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pele_Yoetz)" ([Bizayon](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.58b.18?lang=en&p2=Pele_Yoetz.25.1&lang2=en)) explains, since G-d made the Adam in his image, therefore humiliating a person [by striking them in the face] is as if they're humiliating the Shekhina, God forbid.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damages_(Jewish_law)#Shame_or_Humiliation):

> For the sages, it was deemed of utmost importance to avoid shaming
>   another person. Hence, they sought to impose liability for humiliating
>   personal injury, regardless of the physical effects of the injury.
>
> But for certain acts of violence that involve very little pain and no
>   permanent disablement, but mainly disgrace, the sages fixed a scale of
>   compensation, namely: for a stroke with the fist, one sela or shekel;
>   for a slap with the open hand, two hundred zuzin; for a back-handed
>   slap, or for pulling a man's ear or hair, or tearing off his cloak or
>   a woman's headgear, or spitting at a person if the spittle reaches his
>   flesh, four hundred zuzin (B. Ḳ. viii. 6).

Comment: Thank you for this well-researched answer. I find it interesting how different it deals with different ways of striking someone. Originally I had in my mind there might be a relation to which hand you're using, but seems there's not much information out there